# Parsing nested data in boost-spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I need parse some text-tree :

```
std::string data = "<delimiter>field1a fieald1b fieald1c<delimiter1>subfield11<delimiter1>subfieald12<delimiter1>subfieald13 ... <delimiter>field2a fieald2b fieald2c<delimiter1>subfield21<delimiter1>subfieald22<delimiter1>subfieald23 ..."
```

where `<delimiter>,<delimiter1>` is part of std::string not a single char

It is possible tokenize this string with boost::spirit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list parser is you friend:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// tokenize on '<delimiter1>' and return the vector
rule<std::string::iterator, qi::space_type, std::vector<std::string>()> fields =
    *(char_ - "<delimiter1>") % "<delimiter1>";

std::string data("<delimiter>field1a fieald1b ...");
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > fields_data;

// tokenize of '<delimiter>' and return a vector of vectors
qi::phrase_parse(data.begin(), data.end(), 
    fields % "<delimiter>", qi::space, fields_data);
```

You might need a recent version of Spirit for this to work (Boost V1.47 or SVN trunk).

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented your code its compiling without any errors but lexeme '<delimiter>' is ignored while parsing. I use current stable boost (1.46.1). When I testing on 1.47 I'll write out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could use spirit to do this format but it seems to me to be much more than you need.

I would just code the tokenise myself directly using std string functions. Alternately boost:regex should do this very easily for you.

Comment: Hand-written parsers very quickly grown to become unmaintainable piles of spaghetti code as your needs evolve.  Much better to start from a principled starting point.

Comment: But his spec is very simple - really tokeniser is a better description of what he needs than parser